# Angular JS $http.get() $scope Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to accomplish what seems should be a simple task but i'm stumped.

Here is the simplest example I could come up with.

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script>
            var test = 'Hello World';

            var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
            myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
                $scope.testStr = test;
            });

            myApp.run(function($http){
                test = 'scope updates'; 
                $http.get("controllers/getTestStr.jsp").success(function (data) {
                    //console.log('returned');
                    test = 'scope does not update';
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="myCtrl" style="padding:10px;">
        <p>{{testStr}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Essentially I am initializing a variable called test and binding the variable to the `testStr` scope.  If I update the test variable on `run()` the testStr updates in the view.  But if I update that same variable via a `$http.get` request then the view never gets updated.  Why is this?  What is the best way to accomplish this task?

Any enlightenment is greatly appreciated.

*Anguar v1.2.16*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your issue is Angular related. `test` and `testStr` are just plain old JavaScript strings so when you set one to be equal to a new string it creates a new variable and won't effect any other variables. If you want multiple variables to have a reference to the same string you'd have to put it in an object. e.g.:

```
var a = {str: 'my string'}
var b = a;

b.str = 'new string';

//now a.str and b.str both equal 'new string'
```

The only reason you see the changes you make in the `run()` block is because it executes before `$scope.testStr = test;`